# What does the diode in this D flip-flop "One-shot" do?

Tags: diodes, flipflop, multivibrator, monostable, one-shot

[image: Monostable multivibrator]

Does this diode help discharge the capacitor once the flip-flop is reset?

Thanks in advanced.

(Image was taken from http://educypedia.karadimov.info/library/oneshots.pdf)

Comment: Yes, it does. The capacitor will discharge near-instantly through the diode and the output.

Comment: More importantly, it *prevents* the capacitor from charging instantly when the output goes high.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. D flip-flop table with the only two conditions of interest highlighted.*

Since the *D* input is permanently high there are only two conditions of interest.

1. *CL* going high will set *Q*.
2. *R* going high will reset *Q*.

R and C in your sample circuit will have a time constant given by $$ \tau = RC = 1M \times 0.1 \mu = 0.1~s $$

- On each rising edge of CL, Q will turn on for about 0.1 s, R will go high and Q will turn off again.
- The diode provides a rapid discharge path for C so that the circuit won't be held in RESET mode for the next 0.1 s and is ready to be re-triggered.
- Maximum pulse detection rate without skipping pulses will be in the order of \$ \frac {1}{\tau} = \frac {1}{0.1} = 10~Hz \$.